# Intuition for why ln|x| is the integral for 1/x

Tags: calculus

Simple questions here, but looking at the graphs of $ln|x|$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ I don't see why this works.  Especially from the perspective of "integral is area under the curve", in the interval x = (0,1), $\frac{1}{x}$ is positive while $ln|x|$ is negative.

Also, because $ln|x|$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ are both undefined for $x = 0$, does that mean that $\int_{-a}^{b} \frac{1}{x+c}$ is always undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the integral $$\int_{0}^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}$$ diverges, but to highlight the intuition, let's consider $$\int_{\varepsilon}^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}$$
for some (small) $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$. Then, the Newton–Leibniz rule implies that $$\int_{\varepsilon}^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=\ln(1)-\ln(\varepsilon)=-\ln(\varepsilon).$$
Since $\varepsilon<1$, $\ln(\varepsilon)<0$, implying that the integral will be positive. There is no contradiction here!

More generally, suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$. If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, the value of the integral will be $$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a).$$
That is, all that matters is the *difference* between the values of $F$ evaluated at the two endpoints of the interval. The actual *sign* of $F$ throughout the interval does not matter.